# How do I add line breaks/images to SQL database/MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

Sorry for the terrible title. I followed [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation) MVC tutorial on asp.net to the end.  After I finished it, I realized that I had a personal use for this.  I'm making a site where I can organize D&D spells (since the player's handbook is so bad about that).  It'll be local only, so I'm not worried about infringing Wizards' rights to it.  I threw it up on azure real quick for the sake of getting help with an issue I'm having.  If you look at the link below, you'll see a massive block of text for the description.  When editing it, I tried adding a `<br>` or a `&NewLine;`, but they both cause errors when I try to save.  How can I format this text that's stored as a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in an Azure SQL database.  I also would like to store links to images in the description as well and have them displayed, but putting `<img src=xxxx/>` errors too.

Any ideas?

Here's what the display in my View looks like:

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
</dt>

<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
</dd>
```

http://spellbook3411.azurewebsites.net/spells/Details/152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing HTML tags in your column in the database you should use Html.Raw like this in your razor view :

@Html.Raw(Model.MyPropWithHtmlTags)

Comment: That definitely seems like it'll be what I need.  So for right now, for Description, I have this:

<dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>

So how would I implement your solution

Comment: replace the @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description) with @Html.Raw(Model.Description)

Comment: When I do that, I get that `model` doesn't exist in this context

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks.  Umm, so I think that'll work as far as displaying goes, but whenever I type HTML in edit to submit to the database, I get a 
`potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`

Comment: That's another question, anyways: Add this to the top of your controller action: [ValidateInput(false)]

Comment: And hope a hacker doesn't bother with your personal site.

Comment: Yes, Kyle is right, this is potential thread, as you allow users to put in HTML code there...

Comment: Well, it's only going to be on my LAN in the future, so I'm not really worried about Hackers

Comment: The validateinput(false) totally worked.  Thanks guys!  I acknowledge the risks